# Why won't this compile? Tribonacci function

Tags: c++, stdvector

This problem is similar to Fibonacci sequence except we are adding the last three numbers together instead of the last 2. It is being called Tribonacci.

INPUT: array/list of 3 beginning numbers in the sequence and (n) how long you want the final pattern to be like 30 numbers or just 10 numbers etc.,

OUTPUT: An array that is n long, contains the beginning 3 numbers, and is the correct Tribonacci pattern.

I'm doing this in the codewars website so the error codes are a little different. Most of the reason I'm having trouble here is because I don't know too much about vectors and I can't cout.

```
std::vector<int> tribonacci(std::vector<int> signature, int n)
{
    std::vector<int> result;

    //add last 3 to get n

   result[0]=signature[0];
   result[1]=signature[1];
   result[2]=signature[2];
   std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;


  for(int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
    result[i] = signature[i-1] + signature[i-2] + signature[i-3];
    std::cout << result[i];
  }

    return result;
}
```

I get error code 139 and no tests pass.

Comment: `result` is an empty vector. `result[x]` exhibits undefined behavior for any value of `x`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: Replace `std::vector<int> result;` with `std::vector<int> result(n);` to create `result` with `n` elements instead of empty, then you will be able to set its values later.

Comment: Besides, `result[i]` should be calculated with previous values of `result`, not of `signature`

Answer (score 1):

You can't access indices of a vector without having values there first because it's undefined behaviour. You might end in a sigsegv, for example. There are several ways to deal with it, for instance:

1. Init `result` vector with n values instead of vector of size 0:

```
std::vector<int> result(n);
// + setting first 3 values from signature vector
```

2. Use `push_back` instead of indexing:

```
auto result = signature;
```

and then in the loop:

```
int sum = result[i-1] + result[i-2] + result[i-3];
result.push_back(sum)
```

Note: `result` vector is used here instead of `signature` to compute next element in the result sequence.

---

By the way, you might be interested in a more general function `x_bonacci`:

Assuming we have a function that sums elements of part of a given vector, like:

```
int sum_subvector(std::vector<int>& vector, int start, int how_many){
    int sum = 0;
    auto start_it = vector.begin() + start;
    auto end_it = start_it + how_many;
    for(auto it = start_it; it != end_it; ++it)
        sum += *it;
    return sum;
}
```

We can have such x-bonacci function:

```
// get n-element fibonacci sequence 
// where each element in the sequence consists of a sum of previous x elements
// signature - vector with first x elements of the sequence
std::vector<int> x_bonacci(std::vector<int> signature, int n){  
    int x = signature.size(); // for tribonacci x = 3

    if(n < x){
        return std::vector<int>(signature.begin(), signature.begin() + n);
    }

    auto result = signature;
    for(int i = x; i < n; i++){
        auto next_result = sum_subvector(result, i - x, x); 
        result.push_back(next_result);    
    }
    return result;
}
```

with few changes you can turn it into `tribonacci`.

Example of usage:

```
// get first 20 elements of the tribonacci sequence:
auto tribo20 = x_bonacci({0, 1, 2}, 20);
for(auto x: tribo20)
    std::cout << x << ',';
```